# doing a group by on two fields

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to do a group by whereby I am going to join a table that is in the many side to a table on the one side so I will need to do a group by to get the right result. the problem I have is when I do a group by using one column then I am still get duplicates in the many side table so I have to do another group by using another field but not sure if I am getting the right result can someone see if I am doing this the right way

```
select max(id),
sale_id,
max(date)
from sales
group by sale_id
```

So what I want to happen is for the max date to calculate first and then the max id to be calculated I don't want them to be calculated at the same time as that may cause the data to not appear as expected

so ill give an example

i have the three columns

```
id       date                 sale_id
1        01-01-2022            5675
2        02-01-2022            5675
3        05-01-2022            5675
4        02-01-2022            5676
5        03-01-2022            5676
6        03-01-2022            5676
```

so as we can see the sale_id 5676 has two sales on the 03-01-2022. so i want to group by date first to return the following

```
id         date           sale_id
3          05-01-2022       5675
5          03-01-2022       5676
6          03-01-2022       5676
```

once i get back this result set I then want to group by id to get back my desired result set

```
id         date             sale_id
3          05-01-2022         5675
6          03-01-2022         5676
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the aggregate `max` function with [the `last` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LAST.html#GUID-4E16BC0E-D3B8-4BA4-8F97-3A08891A85CC) to get both values with one aggregation (group-by):

```
select max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by sale_date, id) as id,
  max(sale_date) as sale_date,
  sale_id
from your_table
group by sale_id;
```

| ID | SALE_DATE | SALE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 05-JAN-22 | 5675 |
| 6 | 03-JAN-22 | 5676 |

('date' is a reserved word so I've assumed the column is actually called something more meaningful like 'sale_date'.)

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d7f904b52f6617bc3e07aeafe6be8a55)

You can use the same technique after you join two tables together.

Answer (score 0):

You could always partition your rows:

```
SELECT id, [date], sale_id
FROM
(
     SELECT MAX(Id) AS Id, [date], sale_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sale_id ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS RowNum
     FROM Sales
     GROUP BY [Date], sale_id
)x
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I call your table as "your_table". 'date_id' is name of column you call 'date', column name should not be the same as format names like date,varchar, number and ... .

Ok, Just do something like this:

```
with b as (select distinct sale_id,max(date_id) over (partition by sale_id) date_id from your_table)
select max(a.id),
       a.date_id,
       a.sale_id 
                from your_table a join b 
                on a.sale_id=b.sale_id and 
                   a.date_id=b.date_id 
                   group by a.date_id,a.sale_id ;
```

date_id is in date format. I used 'over partition by ...'.

Literally, the PARTITION BY clause sets the range of records that will be used for each "GROUP" within the OVER clause.

try 'over partition' family. it works.